# Capture a cell value which updates to a static cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have written a straightforward google sheets which dynamically captures closing stock prices in cells in a column for about 30 specific stocks (using their ticker symbol) at the end of the stock market close. At next trading day close these values are ***overwritten*** by the new closing prices.

I'd like to preserve these closing prices for some period of time, say a week, such that I can see how a specific stock changes over a week by looking at its closing price over the week. Ideally these stock prices would be written to a new sheet which holds data for a week.

Perhaps a script would accomplish this, but I was thinking that I could do this without a script based on writing a cell value (the one that updates each day) at 4pm ET to a specific cell in a static, non-updating worksheet. The issue is that static cell would need to change by 1 each day.  Not sure how to do this without a script and that's probably beyond my scope.

Was hoping I could do this with GOOGLEFINANCE but I don't see a way.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi. (untested) Have you considered adding seven columns adjacent to your existing column of data. Use the same formula in the extra columns, but make the effective data one day, two days, three days, etc after the data in the main column. This approach ought to yield a row of values for a week prior to the current date

Comment: Thank you - I will try that.